# SAXParser и BASE64

Tags: java

Столкнулся с такой непонятной ситуацией: парсирую xml используя SAXParser. Содержимое одного из тэгов - некий рисунок в BASE64 размером 90-100 кб. Парсер из этого объема данных дергает кусок произвольной длины (но из каждого конкретного рисунка всегда один и тот же кусок). Что может быть?

Comment: *парсирую* слово то какое красивое...

Comment: "кусок произвольной длины (но из каждого конкретного рисунка всегда один и тот же кусок" нипанять =(

Comment: > "кусок произвольной длины (но из каждого конкретного рисунка всегда один и тот же кусок" нипанять =(

@Gorets, длина разная для разных рисунков. Для каждого - своя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандарт SAX'а допускает чтение длинного текста (каковым по сути является бинарник закодированный Base64) несколькими кусками. Вам внутри парсера надо распознавать начало и конец тега с тем чтобы все текстовые куски внутри тега сшивать в один большой текст. Например так:

```
    DefaultHandler defaultHandler = new DefaultHandler() {
    StringWriter charsWriter = new StringWriter();

    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) {
        charsWriter.write(ch, start, length);
    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) {
        String allTheChars = charsWriter.toString();
    }
};
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, попробую.

Comment: попровал, дело в том, что length в методе characters не правильный. Элементарно посчитал кол-во символов в содержимом тэга, получилось например 65000, а length=15000. Складывается впечатление, что парсер упирается в некий символ и считает его как endElement.

Comment: так он прочитает до 15 тыщь и потом еще раз заново вызовется уже с параметрами start=15000, length=15000 и т.д. пока не прочтет все 65 тыс. Твоя задача все сконкатеринировать и составить полную строку 65 тыс. длиной